# flutter: itemCount does not update automatically

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my app, I have a `listViewBuilder` which has `itemCount`. I called this itemCount on my appBar (by setting states) so it can show me the number of lists on that Listview. However, the item count does not update unless I click on one of the lists before it updates. How can I do it so that immediately I navigate to the list page the number of list on that page updates automatically?

```
int? number = 0; //this will be shown in my `appBar`.

ListView.builder(
         itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
         itemBuilder: (context, index){
         final length = snapshot.data!.docs.length;
            return Card(
                 child: ListTile(
                     onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedAds = snapshot.data!.docs[index]; 
                            number = length; 
                          });  
)
)
}
)
```

As shown in the first picture, when I navigate to the page number of driver is still 0 even though it countains an item.

[not updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4poMh.png)

But in the second picture, after I click on listTile, it updates.

[updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0vfe.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using StreamBuilder for getting data & if so have you placed appBar inside the StreamBuilder?

Comment: Yes, I'm using StreamBuilder for getting the data, but I'm not placed appBar in the StreamBuilder. That's why I setState. Do I have to use StreamBuilder seperately in the appBar?

Comment: My StreamBuilder is in the body of the Scaffold

Comment: you may try with returning Scaffold from StreamBuilder

Comment: I will try that in about an hour. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As it is clear, the reason that when you tap each item in your list and your number is updated is that you called a setState method on each item on tap, and when you tap them, your number is updated, but for you inside the appbar, probably due to changes You don't listen to the length of your list or you don't update it. There are different ways to do this. For example, like the example below, you can update your app using [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html). I hope I explained it clearly and it helps you.

```dart
int? number = 0;

Future<int> getListCount() async {
 // Replace this with your actual data fetching logic
 // For example, if you are fetching data from Firestore:
 // var snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('your_collection').get();
 // return snapshot.docs.length;
 return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => 10); // Simulated data
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
     title: Text('Your App'),
     actions: [
       FutureBuilder<int>(
         future: getListCount(),
         builder: (context, snapshot) {
           if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
             return CircularProgressIndicator(); 
           } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
             return Text('Error'); 
           } else {
             number = snapshot.data;
             return Text('$number Lists');
           }
         },
       ),
     ],
   ),
   body: ListView.builder(
     itemCount: number,
     itemBuilder: (context, index) {
       // Your list item builder logic here
     },
   ),
 );
}
```

or you can use [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and wrap the scaffold widget with it and update and manage your whole states with it like the below example

```dart
class ListPage extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
     stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('your_collection').snapshots(),
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
       if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
         return Scaffold(
           appBar: AppBar(
             title: Text('Loading...'),
           ),
           body: CircularProgressIndicator(), // Show a loading indicator for the body
         );
       } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
         return Scaffold(
           appBar: AppBar(
             title: Text('Error'),
           ),
           body: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
         );
       } else {
         final docs = snapshot.data!.docs;
         final itemCount = docs.length;
         return Scaffold(
           appBar: AppBar(
             title: Text('$itemCount Lists'), // Display the item count
           ),
           body: ListView.builder(
             itemCount: itemCount,
             itemBuilder: (context, index) {
               // Extract data from Firestore document and use it in your ListTile
               final data = docs[index].data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
               final title = data['title']; // Replace 'title' with your field name
               return ListTile(
                 title: Text(title),
                 // Add more ListTile properties as needed
               );
             },
           ),
         );
       }
     },
   );
 }
}
```

And I also suggest you check this question, it might be useful for you
[How to wrap a StreamBuilder class with a Column or ListView class in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51400549/how-to-wrap-a-streambuilder-class-with-a-column-or-listview-class-in-flutter)

Comment: It seem to me that the future that was built is only used to get itemCount but not actual data from fairestore. If not so could you help me to get the data using TileList. I tried all I could but couldn't get it. Moreover, I'm used to using the StreamBuilder to fetch my data

Comment: Or do I need to create a whole new FutureBuilder/StreamBuilder for the body of the scaffold to fetch the data for the ListViewBuilder?

Comment: Yes, I think you can do this. I will change the answer for you and add a new example.